# Sizeof in C++ and how to calculate pointer length?

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof

Can someone explain the following code snippet for me?

```
// Bind base object so we can compute offsets
// currently only implemented for indexes.
template<class DataObj> void BindAsBase(DataObj &rowbuf)
{
    // Attempting to assign working_type first guarantees exception safety.
    working_type = DTL_TYPEID_NAME (rowbuf);
    working_addr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&rowbuf);
    working_size = sizeof(rowbuf);
}
```

My problem is what is the result of sizeof(rowbuf)? Is it the length of DataObj or either the length of Byte*? why?

Another question: why there is a need to calculate offset of pointer? What is the usual use of it?

What is sizeof(working_addr) equal to?

Comment: It would help to have more context. Typically you don't use reinterpret_cast and sizeof in C++, and you are using a nonstandard typeid function.

What does this code go into? What does is this info used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sizeof(rowbuf) returns the length in bytes of an object of type DataObj.
Note that rowbuf is *no* pointer, but it is a reference which is quite a difference.

If you want to calculate the size of y DataObj pointer use sizeof(&rowbuf) or sizeof(DataObj*).

Answer (score 3):

sizeof(rowBuf) is the number of bytes used by the DataObj type. It is computed at compile time.

Usually it is needed to call methods on a given instance without knowning about the object (so-called method binding like in boost::bind) these bound instance-method can be used as callbacks for algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MSDN page about sizeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91.aspx):

> When the sizeof operator is applied to
>   a reference, the result is the same as
>   if sizeof had been applied to the
>   object itself

So sizeof(rowbuf) == sizeof(DataObj)

Answer (score 1):

`rowbuf` is a `DataObj &`.  So you'd expect `sizeof(rowbuf)` to be equal to `sizeof(DataObj)`.

The other day I learned the Visual Studio **debugger** has a bug with `sizeof` and references.  It will actually give you the size of a pointer rather than the size of the object.  The compiler does the right thing.